# Search files in C# using mask

Tags: c#, regex, search, mask

In my ASP.NET MVC application I need to organize filter for a table what will use search masks (symbols like ***, ? etc). For example in Windows if we put '*.txt' to search it will return all files with txt extension.

As far as I remember mask with '?' symbol means any 1 symbol. And if I use it at Regex expression it means not greedy search.

Do you know is there some standard convertor at C# from this masks to regex expressions? Or I need create everything myself?

Some examples: "test1" and "test2" are in list.

- If we use mask "*st1" it means that any symbols in any count can be before 'st1' so in a result we will have "test1"
- Mask "test?" means that after 'test' we can have any symbol but only one. So in a result we'll have both "test1" and "test2"

Comment: Give some example of the data you have and the result you want to have. What have you tried so far?

Comment: `?` means "not greedy" only if it succeeds a quantifier. `?` by itself means "zero or one" (i.e. a quantifier itself).

Answer (score 0):

Your title is 'search files...' - so maybe you can use the Directory API, which accepts wildcards?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413233.aspx

Btw I realise this is a long shot and you may be doing something else.

Comment: Unfortunately I need not only files but some data from tables too